# android in-app billing Security verify method always return false

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have built an android application that is providing to the users the ability to purchase an items, and the google purchase dialog is return payment successfully, but on activity result the application failed in Security.java verify method always return false "sig.verify(Based64.decode(signature))".

any help why it's happening and what I have to do.
I have published the app to the play store and I do not use the android.test.* sku I have my own skus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you initialize it correctly?

Get public key:

```
public PublicKey getAPKKey(String keyFactoryAlgorithm) throws Exception{
    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode("...your google play public key...", Base64.DEFAULT);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(keyFactoryAlgorithm);
    return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
}
```

You can find your public key in the Google Play Developer Console.

Then verify the signature:

```
// get purchase data
Bundle ownedItems = ... query purchases
String purchaseData = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST").get(0); // just index 0 for demonstration
String signature = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST").get(0); // just index 0 for demonstration

PublicKey pkey = getAPKKey("RSA");
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
sig.initVerify(pkey);
sig.update(purchaseData.getBytes());

if(sig.verify(Base64.decode(signature, Base64.DEFAULT))) {
    // ok
} else {
    // not ok
}
```

Comment: @AmjadOmari make sure you import the right Base64, as from android.util.Base64. It is present since API Version 8 and should be there definitely.

Comment: I have imported the correct one for Base64, but the sig.verify still return false and I have checked that I'm using the correct google play public key "license key for this application",

Comment: @AmjadOmari are you sure you removed all linebreaks from the public key?